# How can I find Drupal pages not listed in XML Sitemap module?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-modules

I recently inherited a Drupal 8/9 site.  I've got the XML Sitemap module deployed.  Is there a way for me to find pages that are *NOT* included in the sitemap?  I'm concerned there's a lot of ROT that I can't see.

Thanks!

Comment: A bit more background.  I chose a random search term and found pages that are published but do not show in the sitemap.  They have the sitemap permissions turned off.  I'd like to know how many more of those I have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to find pages that are not listed in the sitemap.xml.

Maybe, what you can do is just enable sitemap config on every content type, vocabulary, etc. Then you'd queue and generate sitemap again.